# addEventListener Shows same value for all events

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

All, I have been trying different things for few hours now but I couldn't get around this issue, I have this function which accepts the JSON -

I can `createElement('a')` : FINE
I can `set` all element properties such as `href` etc : FINE
I can `appendChild(a)` with required element `tags` : FINE
But I cannot set `a.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("clicked - " + a.id) }, false);` Everytime i click on any href, it shows the last value

```
function setTags(tagsJson) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(tagsJson); 
    var a = null;
    var linkText = null; 
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (typeof (obj[i].Tag_name) === 'undefined' || obj[i].Tag_name === null) {
           // DO NOTHING
        }
        else
        {   a = document.createElement('a');
            linkText = document.createTextNode(obj[i].Tag_name);
            a.appendChild(linkText);            
            a.href = "#";               
            a.textContent = obj[i].Tag_name;
            a.className = "badge badge-success";                                      
            document.getElementById("tags").appendChild(a);

          // HERE IS THE ISSUE
            a.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("clicked - " + a.textContent) }, false); 

       }
     }
}
```

an example if JSON has the following values

`{\"Tag_id\":12,\"Tag_name\":\"Aston Martin\"},{\"Tag_id\":13,\"Tag_name\":\"Cars\"}]"}`

It should append unique text at `textContent` such as 'Aston Martin', 'Auston' and 'Cars' but on clicking on any item, alter is shown as `Cars` although Text in the link shows correct values.

[image]

As per the above screenshot, i can see the text values are fine, but addEventListener only shows last value on CLICK

I think I am missing the understanding of `addEventListener`?

How can I tackle this issue

Cheers

Comment: You should try getting not a.textContent ,but this.textContent to reffer to exact value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `a.textContent` use `this.textContent`

```
a.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("clicked - " + this.textContent) }, false);
```

By the time this *event listener* is executed, *for-loop* has already been executed till `i < obj.length` is satisfied, which is why `a` is always the final one.

Answer (score 1):

The function will trigger only when you click on the item, so when you click it will take the variable a which is declared outside of your for loop , and the a preserve the last item from loop.

Instead of using the variable a use the the current context into the function by using the word **this**.

```
a.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("clicked - " + this.textContent) }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of how you write the alert function:

```
a.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("clicked - " + a.textContent);  // <---- THIS LINE
}, false);
```

In the line, `a.textContent` will get the `textContent` value from `a`.

In your implementation, the value of `a` is changing every loop. So, the `a` value the function gets will be the `a` value from the last loop. Therefore, you will always get the last value of `a` only.

To counter that, you can use another way to call for `a.textContent` within the function.

There is two ways according to your current implementation:

**One: Use `event.target`**

```
a.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // event is an event object passed by the `addEventListener` function
    // where event.target === the DOM element that activates the listener
    alert("clicked - " + event.target.textContent);
}, false);
```

**Two: use `this`**

```
a.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // `this` value === the element that activates this event listener.
    alert("clicked - " + this.textContent);
}, false);
```

**Working example**

```js
var json = "[{\"Tag_id\":12,\"Tag_name\":\"Aston Martin\"},{\"Tag_id\":13,\"Tag_name\":\"Cars\"}]";

setTags(json);

function setTags(tagsJson) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(tagsJson); 
    var a = null;
    var linkText = null; 
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (typeof obj[i].Tag_name === 'undefined' || obj[i].Tag_name === null) {
           // DO NOTHING
        }
        else
        {   a = document.createElement('a');
            linkText = document.createTextNode(obj[i].Tag_name);
            a.appendChild(linkText);            
            a.href = "#";               
            a.textContent = obj[i].Tag_name;
            a.className = "badge badge-success";                                      
            document.getElementById("tags").appendChild(a);

          // HERE IS THE ISSUE
            a.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("clicked - " + this.textContent) }, false); 

       }
     }
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tags"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical misuse of closures.

You are declaring your `a` variable outside of your for loop and more importantly your click callback function. So as you iterate through, your `a` is overriden. Finally each time you call your click function, `a` will have his value set to the last value set during the for loop.

So in your case you will always have

```
a.textContent = obj[obj.length - 1].Tag_name;
```

To make it work as expected, you need to retrieve you `<a>` from the click event itself. This can be done like so

```
a.addEventListener("click", function (event) { // use event here to find your element
   const a = document.getElementById(event.target.id); // This is the element that was clicked
   alert("clicked - " + a.textContent)
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause the function binding after for-loop

```
for (var i = 0;i<10;i ++){
    aLis[i].onclick = (function(num){
      return function(){
        alert(num)
      };                        
    })(i);    
}
```

Look at this :

http://jsbin.com/liyeqamone/5/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: #use let in es6

for (let i = 0;i<10;i ++){
     aLis[i].onclick = function(){ alert(i) };
}